# How to keep python project modular?

Tags: python

Context

I've been working on a python project recently, and found modularity very important. For example you made a class with some attributes and some line of code that uses those attributes like

```
a = A()
print("hi"+a.imA)
```

If you were to modify `imA` of class `A` to another type, you would have to modify the print statement.  In my case I had to do this so many times. It was annoying and time consuming. get/set methods would've solved this, but I heard that get/set are not 'good python'. So how would you solve this problem without using get and set methods?

Comment: Take a look on [*properties*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: how would getters and setters have solved your interface breaking a contract? In any case, you could use properties.

Comment: @eddiewould great idea. I'm gonna tell my boss we're reimplementing our 500+kloc (working) python basecode in typescript because "it's type-safe and the IDE can easily find and replace a name", so we can "safely" break a class public API whenever we want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: you would have saved yourself quite some hassle by using string formatting instead of string concatenation, ie:

```
print("hi {}".format(a.imA))
```

Granted, the final result may or not be what you'd expect depending on how `a.imA` type implements `__str__()` and `__repr__()` but at least this will not *break* the code.

wrt/ getters and setters, they are indeed considered rather unpythonic, because python has a strong support for [computed attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and a simple generic implementation is available as [the builtin `property` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

*NB: actually what's considered unpythonic is to systematically use implementation attributes and getters/setters (either explicits or - as is the case with computed attributes - implicits) when a plain public attribute is enough, and this is considered unpythonic because you can always turn a plain attribute into a computed one without breaking the client code (assuming of course you don't change the type nor semantic of the attribute) - something that was not possible with early OOPLs like Smalltalk, C++ or Java (Smalltalk being a bit of a special case actually but that's another topic).*

In your case, if the point was to change the *stored* value's type without breaking the API, the simple obvious canonical solution was to use a `property` delegating to an implementation attribute:

before:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        # `bar`  is expected to be the string representation of an int.
        self.bar = bar

    def frobnicate(self, val):
        return (int(self.bar) + val) / 2
```

after:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        # `bar`  is expected to be the string representation of an int.
        self.bar = bar

    # but we want to store it as an int
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return str(self._bar)

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = int(value)

    def frobnicate(self, val):
        # internally we use the implementation attribute `_bar`
        return (self._bar + val) / 2
```

And you now have the value stored internally as an int, but the public interface is (almost) exactly the same - the only difference being that passing something that cannot be passed to `int()` will raise at the expected place (when you set it) instead than breaking at the most unexpected one (when you call `.frobnicate()`)

Now note that that changing the type of a public attribute is just like changing the return type of a getter (or the type of a setter argument) - in both cases you *are* breaking the contract - so if what you wanted was *really* to change the type of `A.imA`, neither getters nor properties would have solved your issue - getters and setters (or in Python computed attributes) can only protect you from *implementation* changes.

EDIT: oh and yes: this has nothing to do with modularity (which is about writing decoupled, self-contained code that's easier to read, test, maintain and eventually reuse), but with encapsulation (which aim is to make the public interface resilient to implementation changes).

Answer (score 0):

First, use

```
print(f"hi {a.imA}")  # Python 3.6+
```

or

```
print("hi {}".format(a.imA)) # all Python 3
```

instead of

```
print("hi"+a.imA)
```

That way, `str` will be called automatically on each argument.

Then define a `__str__` function in all your classes, so that `print`ing any class always works.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._member_1 = "spam"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"A(member 1: {self._member_1})"
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitely define `__str__()` for string formatting to work - Python already provides a default implementation (even for python2 "old style" classes). And while I totally agree on using string formatting instead of concatenation, this doesn't answer the whole question.

Comment: But it calls the default `__repr__` which in most case does not print what you want. Properties does not help with the fact of printing everything cleanly with a simple `print(my_object.my_member)`, whatever the type of `my_member` or `my_object`.

Comment: you state "define a __str__ function in all your classes, so that printing any class always works", which implies (or "can easily be interpreted as") it would otherwise break - which is not the case,  hence the first part of my comment.